# vuetify : cannot trigger click on radio button

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am trying to the the follwoing comonent with radio buttons

```
<template>
  <form id="contactForm" @submit="sendMessage()">
        <v-radio-group row :mandatory="false" :model="gender" data-vv-name="gender" v-validate="'required'" name="gender">
          <v-radio @click='changeGender("f")' :label='genderLabel("f")' :value="f"></v-radio>
          <v-radio @click='changeGender("m")' :label='genderLabel("m")' :value="m"></v-radio>
        </v-radio-group>
        ...
   </form>
 </template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "contactForm",
  data() {
    return {
      gender: "f"
    };
  },
  ...
  methods: {
   ...
    changeGender: function(value) {
      console.log("gender changed to: ", value);
      this.gender = value;
    }
    ...
</script>
```

Test

```
  const radioInput = wrapper.findAll('input[type="radio"]');
  radioInput.at(1).setChecked(); // input element value is changed, v-model is not
  radioInput.at(1).trigger('click') // v-model updated
```

but I get an error...  click on the second radio button [] does not change the value..

where am I wrong ?  is 'click' ok or shoudl I sue another trigger ? ( change?)

thanks for feedback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you mean Something like this  simply setting v-model

`<v-radio-group v-model="boolean" row class="ma-2">
    <v-radio label="Yes" value="Yes"></v-radio>
    <v-radio label="No" value="No"></v-radio>
</v-radio-group>`

Comment: thanks ...  I updated my code with a v-model and using @change on v-radio buttons